# MySQL - Update table field from query in one statement

Tags: mysql

I successfully managed to retrieve users with 2 or less posts from a database and display the result of that query which looks like this:

```html
SELECT Users.*, count( Posts.user_id ) 
FROM Posts LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.user_id = Posts.user_id
GROUP BY Posts.user_id
HAVING count( Posts.user_id ) < 2
```

What i would like to achieve next is to update a field called active for all users of that query, so i tried to add an UPDATE statement together with the first query:

```html
UPDATE Users
SET Users.Active = 3
WHERE count( Posts.user_id ) < 2
```

But i can't get it to work. Where should the UPDATE part be positioned or maybe should it be run separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In where statement you need to select count of posts per user and check if it is less than 2.

```
    UPDATE Users
    SET Users.Active = 3
    WHERE (SELECT count( Posts.user_id ) 
           FROM Posts 
           WHERE Users.user_id = Posts.user_id
           GROUP BY Posts.user_id) < 2
```

Comment: Worked like a breeze, thanks a lot for the fast answer Dusan!